# Go - calculate the cidr below one bit of the cidr provided

Tags: go, cidr

**Ask**

How do you calculate the cidr below one bit of the cidr provided?

**Given:**

a network CIDR : (192.168.0.0/16)

**wanted result**

192.168.0.0/17, 192.168.128.0/17

Using packages such as the default `net` package and `github.com/brotherpowers/ipsubnet`, `github.com/seancfoley/ipaddress-go/ipaddr` did not get the desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To split a network in two, increment the length of the prefix by one. That gives you the lower half. To compute the second half, increment the network part by one (error handling omitted for brevity):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
    "net/netip"
)

func main() {
    p := netip.MustParsePrefix("192.168.0.0/16")
    lo, hi := split(p)
    fmt.Println(lo, hi) // 192.168.0.0/17 192.168.128.0/17
}

func split(p netip.Prefix) (lo, hi netip.Prefix) {
    p = p.Masked()
    lo, _ = p.Addr().Prefix(p.Bits() + 1)

    delta := big.NewInt(1)
    delta.Lsh(delta, uint(lo.Addr().BitLen()-lo.Bits()))

    n := new(big.Int).SetBytes(lo.Addr().AsSlice())
    n.Add(n, delta)

    hiIP, _ := netip.AddrFromSlice(n.Bytes())
    hi = netip.PrefixFrom(hiIP, lo.Bits())

    return lo, hi
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/0HLqUK0RmVC

Comment: The code above works exactly as I want. Thanks very much for your help :)

Comment: Note for beginners like me who have seen this question > netip packages are available after version 1.18

> https://pkg.go.dev/net/netip?tab=versions

Answer (score 0):

*"Using packages such as the default net package and github.com/brotherpowers/ipsubnet, github.com/seancfoley/ipaddress-go/ipaddr did not get the desired results."*

Here is how to do it with [`github.com/seancfoley/ipaddress-go/ipaddr`](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) (note this code also works with IPv6 and any change in prefix length):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/seancfoley/ipaddress-go/ipaddr"
)

func main() {
    cidr := ipaddr.NewIPAddressString("192.168.0.0/16").GetAddress()
    for i := cidr.AdjustPrefixLen(1).PrefixBlockIterator(); i.HasNext(); {
        fmt.Println(i.Next())
    }
}
```

Output:

```
192.168.0.0/17
192.168.128.0/17
```